# How common is the secondary pronunciation of chestnut (non-silent t)

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries

Until recently, I was convinced that the first t in chestnut is silent. However, the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary includes ['tʃestnʌt] as a secondary variant. Interestingly, the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chestnut_1?q=chestnut) gives ['tʃesnʌt] both as transcriptions and as audio samples, whereas the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chestnut) gives transcriptions with a silent t but (to my ears) an inconsistent audio sample corresponding to ['tʃestnʌt].

I would be quite interested in a rough estimate of how relevant/common ['tʃestnʌt] is.

Comment: It is probably as “often”, whose secondary less common pronunciation has a non silent t.

Comment: Since the American chestnut went extinct, it's not a topic that's come up much. The only time I've heard the [t] pronounced was when someone was reciting the poem with gestures and elocution.

Comment: I do hear that word reasonably often (e.g. "Oh, that old chestnut", and the song "Chestnuts roasting by an open fire").  I have never heard the first T pronounced in conversation or in song.

Comment: Which region's pronunciation are you referring to? AmE or BritE? Or Aus, NZ, Indian, Sth African, Scottish, Welsh, Irish, Caribbean? Which register (eg educated, working class, chatting to the Queen, boozing with the gravediggers)? The pronunciation of older generations (pre Baby Boomers) or millennials? I find I pronounce it either way, depending on how clearly I'm enunciating my words, which in turn depends on my intended audience.